# Gradle Include Pattern

Tags: gradle, gradle-task

Our project recently started separating our unit and integration tests, which used to all be contained within the same package.  We created a task to kick off our integration tests:

```
task intTest(type: test){
  systemProperty ..., System.properties[...]
  systemProperty ..., System.properties[...]
  include '**/*Int*.java','**/*.func*.java','my.path.to.api.files.*'
}
```

However I"ve noticed that none of our Integration nor Functional tests are running.  From what I can see our pattern looks correct.  Any ideas as to why they're not being kicked off?

I am running from CLI using `gradle :application:intTest`

Comment: Since you figured this out on your own, can you remove this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works correctly.  We had a dependency issue which was breaking us.

My app.gradle file was inheriting from a common.gradle file.  The common.gradle file had the same name for one of the tasks, which was breaking the tests.  I changed the name and it works perfectly now.

Comment: Maybe delete it then?